# How to export a canvas created from a HTML that uses a local image as a background?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, html2canvas

I'm developing a utility in HTML/JS which I only use through my browser locally, i.e. all of its data are stored and opened from my local disk. Here's what I'm attempting to do:

1/ I have a block of HTML, in which on of the elements uses an image as its background through the `background-image` property.

2/ I export this part of the document through [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com) to a canvas.

3/ I then want to export the canvas to a PNG file – but that throws a `Tainted canvases may not be exported` exception.

As I looked around for an answer, I tracked the issue down to using a local image as the background. Indeed as long as I comment the background out, everything works fine. The various solutions suggest to set the origin of the images to anonymous, however I'm not using an image element that I could configure like that; I'm using the image as a background. What I can do to make this work?

Comment: Progress! It works if I start Chrome with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` switch. I would still like to have a solution that doesn't require launching the browser with in a particular way, but at least it's a functional workaround

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help:

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
    allowTaint: true,
    foreignObjectRendering: true,
    useCORS: true
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. With these options, I am indeed able to export the canvas, but the resulting render doesn't contain the background image. Is there perhaps something else that I need to do?

Comment: This https://codepen.io/cristobalchao/pen/jRdGOz might work for you.

Comment: It does indeed work, but I'm not sure how to translate that solution to my case of having everything as a local file, i.e. both the HTML and the image being local.